# Visual studio click once application is recognized as a virus

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clickonce

We have a number of applications that we install via clickonce.
Today is monday and since friday there has been no change, or update made
in any of the applications.

This morning we started getting phone calls from clients, the virusscanners
were giving warnings on the *.exe file first it where all clients using
F-Secure but now i also have been contacted by a client that uses norman.

when we scan the sourcecode, or the files from the ftp server we don't get
any errors.

we now think that the exe file does not contain a virus. Does anyone now how
to proceed ? do we have change things in the application properties ?
Does anyone has the same issue ?

Comment: It could be to do with the clients anti-virus, was it updated over the weekend?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do. I've heard of this happening before with ClickOnce, and it's the virus scanner that is at fault, probably something to do with the way ClickOnce actually works.

Comment: Could be so many things...something your app does...a 3rd party DLL you have included, an erroneous signature from the AV app, they got it from a bad place this morning instead of your FTP (poison DNS)...many more.